# Asymptotic notation omega

Tags: big-o

BigO always checks the upper bound. So we can measure ..the way we write the code, so that there will be less time complexity and thus increase our code performance. But why do we use the lowerbound (omega) ? I did not understand the use of omega in real time. Can anybody please suggest me on this

Answer (score 1):

It's a precision feature. It happens that it is usually easier to prove that an algorithm will take, say, `O(n)` operations to complete than proving that it will take *at least* `O(n)` operations (BTW, in this context *operation* means *elementary* computations such as the logical and arithmetic ones.)

By providing a lower bound, you are also giving an estimate of the *best case* scenario, as the big-O notation only provides an upper bound.

From a practical viewpoint, this has the benefit of telling that no matter what, *any* algorithm will require so many (elementary) steps (or more).

Note also, that it is also useful to have estimates of the *average*, the *worst* and the *best* cases, because these will shed more light on the *complexity* of the algorithm.

There are problems whose inherent complexity is known to be at least of some order (meaning there is a mathematical theorem proving the fact). So, no matter the algorithm, these problems cannot be solved with less that a certain number of calculations. This is also useful because lets you know whether a given algorithm is sub-optimal or matches the inherent complexity of the problem.

Comment: I understand from the above discussion that omega says "this function will execute atleast these many number of times" i.e, the lower bound (or minimum value).Example:
   for  i = 0; i < n; I++
        for j = 0; j < n; j++ .  (Note: This is a nested for loop for the above for loop. Formatting problem)
In this case, we say f(n) = O(n square). What we will consider for omega(n). Is it  f(n) = omega(n) ?

Comment: In the above nested loops, I did not understand, why do we need to consider the lower bound.  As a programmer, I always see what will be the upper bound (or) worst case execution to check the performance of my code. What is the advantage of the lower bound here and can you please provide me with any sample scenario, like why a developer need to provide a lower bound ?

Comment: A lower bound for an algorithm may be useful to discard it, provided its omega is higher than needed. A lower bound for a problem may be useful to accept an algorithm whose big-O matches the lower bound.For instance, given that _sorting_ is known to be `O(nlogn)`, an algorithm whose omega is greater should not be generally used.

Comment: I understand that, we consider a lowerbound, if it shimilar or near to upperbound.. In any given scenario, for any algorithm, which one is measured first (or) given first priority? Upper bound or lowerbound ?

Comment: Upper bounds, i.e., big-Os, are the most commonly used.

Comment: Thank you Leandro. Got a good understanding of asymptotic notations